# Query a parameter (postgresql.conf setting) like "max_connections"

Tags: postgresql, configuration, settings, postgresql-9.1

Does anyone know if it's even possible (and how, if yes) to query a database server setting in PostgreSQL (9.1)?

I need to check the `max_connections` (maximum number of open db connections) setting.

Answer (score 365, accepted):

You can use [**`SHOW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-show.html):

```
SHOW max_connections;
```

This returns the currently effective setting. Be aware that it can differ from the setting in `postgresql.conf` as there are a [multiple ways to set run-time parameters in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html). To reset the "original" setting from `postgresql.conf` in your current session:

```
RESET max_connections;
```

However, not applicable to this particular setting. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html)

> This parameter can only be set at server start.

To see *all* settings:

```
SHOW ALL;
```

There is also [**`pg_settings`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-settings.html):

> The view `pg_settings` provides access to run-time parameters of the
>   server. It is essentially an alternative interface to the `SHOW` and
>   `SET` commands. It also provides access to some facts about each
>   parameter that are not directly available from `SHOW`, such as minimum
>   and maximum values.

For your original request:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_settings
WHERE  name = 'max_connections';
```

Finally, there is [**`current_setting()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE), which can be nested in DML statements:

```
SELECT current_setting('max_connections');
```

Related:

- [How to test my ad-hoc SQL with parameters in Postgres query window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179441/how-to-test-my-ad-hoc-sql-with-parameters-in-postgres-query-window/30179814#30179814)