# Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly

Tags: sql, postgresql, text, similarity, postgresql-performance

I need to create a ranking of similar strings in a table.

I have the following table

```
create table names (
name character varying(255)
);
```

Currently, I'm using **pg_trgm** module which offers the `similarity` function, but I have an efficiency problem. I created an index like the [Postgres manual suggests](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html):

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx ON names USING gist (name gist_trgm_ops);
```

and I'm executing the following query:

```
select (similarity(n1.name, n2.name)) as sim, n1.name, n2.name
from names n1, names n2
where n1.name != n2.name and similarity(n1.name, n2.name) > .8
order by sim desc;
```

The query works, but is really slow when you have hundreds of names. Moreover, maybe I forgot a bit of SQL, but I don't understand why I cannot use the condition `and sim > .8` without getting a "column sim doesn't exist" error.

I'd like any hint to make the query faster.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The way you have it, similarity between every element and every other element of the table has to be calculated (almost a cross join). If your table has 1000 rows, that's already 1,000,000 (!) similarity calculations, *before* those can be checked against the condition and sorted. Scales terribly.

Use [**`SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE) and the [**`%`** operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE) instead. Both are provided by the [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) module. This way, a trigram GiST index can be used to great effect.

The configuration parameter [**`pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/pgtrgm.html#AEN142909) replaced the functions [`set_limit()` and `show_limit()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/release-9-6.html#AEN136570) in Postgres 9.6. The deprecated functions still work (as of Postgres 13). Also, performance of GIN and GiST indexes improved in many ways since Postgres 9.1.

Try instead:

```sql
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.8;  -- Postgres 9.6 or later
  
SELECT similarity(n1.name, n2.name) AS sim, n1.name, n2.name
FROM   names n1
JOIN   names n2 ON n1.name <> n2.name
               AND n1.name % n2.name
ORDER  BY sim DESC;
```

Faster by orders of magnitude, but still slow.

`pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` is a ["customized" option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-custom.html), which can be handled like any other option. See:

- [Query a parameter (postgresql.conf setting) like "max_connections"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288823/query-a-parameter-postgresql-conf-setting-like-max-connections/8288860#8288860)

You may want to restrict the number of possible pairs by adding preconditions (like matching first letters) **before** cross joining (and support that with a matching functional index). The performance of a **cross join** deteriorates with **O(N²)**.

This **does not work** because you cannot refer to output columns in `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses:

```
WHERE ... sim > 0.8
```

That's according to the SQL standard (which is handled rather loosely by certain other RDBMS). On the other hand:

```
ORDER BY sim DESC
```

**Works** because output columns *can* be used in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`. See:

- [PostgreSQL reusing computation result in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218257/postgresql-reusing-computation-result-in-select-query/11218453#11218453)

#### Test case

I ran a quick test on my old test server to verify my claims.
PostgreSQL 9.1.4. Times taken with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` (best of 5).

```
CREATE TEMP table t AS 
SELECT some_col AS name FROM some_table LIMIT 1000;  -- real life test strings
```

First round of tests with GIN index:

```
CREATE INDEX t_gin ON t USING gin(name gin_trgm_ops);  -- round1: with GIN index
```

Second round of tests with GIST index:

```
DROP INDEX t_gin;
CREATE INDEX t_gist ON t USING gist(name gist_trgm_ops);
```

New query:

```sql
SELECT set_limit(0.8);

SELECT similarity(n1.name, n2.name) AS sim, n1.name, n2.name
FROM   t n1
JOIN   t n2 ON n1.name <> n2.name
           AND n1.name % n2.name
ORDER  BY sim DESC;
```

GIN index used,  64 hits: total runtime: 484.022 ms
GIST index used, 64 hits: total runtime: **248.772 ms**

Old query:

```sql
SELECT (similarity(n1.name, n2.name)) as sim, n1.name, n2.name
FROM   t n1, t n2
WHERE  n1.name != n2.name
AND    similarity(n1.name, n2.name) > 0.8
ORDER  BY sim DESC;
```

GIN index **not** used,  64 hits: total runtime: 6345.833 ms
GIST index **not** used, 64 hits: total runtime: 6335.975 ms

Otherwise identical results. Advice is good. And this is for *just 1000 rows*!

#### GIN or GiST?

GIN often provides superior read performance:

- [Difference between GiST and GIN index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975517/difference-between-gist-and-gin-index/28976555#28976555)

[But not in this particular case!](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.40.8)

> This can be implemented quite efficiently by GiST indexes, but not by
> GIN indexes.

- [Multicolumn index on 3 fields with heterogenous data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658515/multicolumn-index-on-3-fields-with-heterogenous-data-types/22675324#22675324)

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you. You're right, I could add a condition on the matching of the first letter, but in those "names" I have names and surnames, sometimes written as "name, surname", sometimes as "surname, name" ... My additional question wasn't related to the use of the alias in the order by, but in the where condition. I thought the similarity could be calculated once for each pair.

Comment: @cdarwin: Ah, I got your subsidiary question wrong, sorry. Amended now. The information was still good - in particular, the link I provided applies, regardless.

Comment: Note `set_limit()` is now deprecated, in lieu of the `similarity_threshold` GUC variable.

Comment: @beldaz: Thanks, I added pointers for the upcoming Postgres 9.6.

Comment: how to print my current `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` ?

Comment: @MaximYefremov: `SHOW pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  may be need `AND n1.name < n2.name`

Comment: And what does that operator do to performance? Isn't it just another way of doing `similarity()` calls?

Comment: @КонстантинВан: Well, yes. But this way a trigram GiST index can be used to great effect. My demo for only 1000 rows should  already be clear. Using the index scales close to linearly, while you get O(N²) without. This is proven good. You may have missed the part where this answer was written in 2012 (and only updated just now).

Comment: Related: [“PostgreSQL doesn’t use index scan with functions within a `WHERE` clause.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60177438/4510033)

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to set the similarity_threshold.
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = _threshold;

"ERROR:  parameter "pg_trgm.similarity_threshold" requires a numeric value
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = _threshold"
PL/pgSQL function questions_get_similar_ones(integer,real) line 3 at SET
SQL state: 22023"

The _threshold is a variable parameter:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION imp.questions_get_similar_ones(
 _question integer,
 _threshold real DEFAULT 0.79)

Comment: @HMarioD: `EXECUTE 'SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = ' || _threshold;` See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36025963/939860 (This is safe against SQLi while the input is a numeric type.)

Comment: I am getting the following error
`ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying % character varying`
@ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: @abatista The operator is provided by the additional module `pg_trgm`. Please read my 2nd paragraph.