# Set default limit for pg_trgm

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

This seems like a really basic question, but how do I change the default limit for the pg_trgm extension? Which is currently 0.3. I have done:

```
select set_limit(0.5)
select show_limit() => 0.5
```

Close the connection, reconnect:

```
select show_limit() => 0.3
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably not a solution, but rather a contribution to a potential solution...

(I am assuming that you want the pg_trgm parameter for all connections to the DB, not just interactive ones?)

It seems that the default 0.3 limit is hard coded in the function:

trgm_op.c:

```
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;

float4          trgm_limit = 0.3f;
```

I am not sure if it can be controlled through any configuration files, so one option could be to change the default in the source file, and re-build the extensions.

Comment: Why is this marked as the answer? It is merely a hint.

Answer (score 8):

Since Postgres 9.6, `pg_trgm` makes use of the Grand Unified Configuration (GUC) system, so one can set a default at the cluster level adding `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.5` in `postgresql.conf`, or at the DB level (`alter database myDB set pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.5` ) or at all other levels allowed by GUC (per user, per function etc)

Comment: Since Postgres 9.6, even. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250001/939860

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this when looking up how to do this in a Ruby on Rails environment. Ended up monkey-patching my adapter:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
private
  alias_method :default_configure_connection, :configure_connection

  # Monkey patch configure_connection because set_limit() must be called on a per-connection basis.
  def configure_connection
    default_configure_connection
    begin
        execute("SELECT set_limit(0.1);")
    rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
        Rails.logger.warn("pg_trgm extension not enabled yet")
    end
  end
end
```

Went this route after seeing other people have this issue, e.g. https://github.com/textacular/textacular/issues/39