# How to run functions every time postgresql starts?

Tags: postgresql

I am using pg_trgm extension for fuzzy search. The default threshold is 0.3 as show in:

```
# select show_limit();
 show_limit 
------------
        0.3
(1 row)
```

I can change it with:

```
# select set_limit(0.1);
 set_limit 
-----------
       0.1
(1 row)

# select show_limit();
 show_limit 
------------
        0.1
(1 row)
```

But when I restart my session, the threshold is reset to default value:

```
# \q

$ psql -Upostgres my_db
psql (9.3.5)
Type "help" for help.

# select show_limit();
 show_limit 
------------
        0.3
(1 row)
```

I want to execute set_limit(0.1) every time I start postgresql. Or in other words, I want to set 0.1 as default value for threshold of pg_trgm extension. How do I do that?

Comment: Just for your sessions (some roles, but not others) or for the whole db?

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608081/set-default-limit-for-pg-trgm. The initial setting seems to be hard coded. I can't think of an easy fix other than running `set_limit()` with the start of every session.

Comment: But is there anything resembling .bashrc for psql session? So when you start psql session, the "select set_limit(0.1)" is executed automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked before:

- [Set default limit for pg_trgm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608081/set-default-limit-for-pg-trgm)

The initial setting is hard coded in the source. One could hack the source and recompile the extension.

To address your comment:
You *could* put a command in your [`psqlrc` or `~/.psqlrc` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#AEN88717). A plain and simple `SELECT` command in a separate line:

```
SELECT set_limit(0.1)
```

Be aware that the additional module is installed *per database*, while `psql` can connect to any database cluster and any database within that cluster. It will cause an error message when connecting to any database where `pg_trgm` is not installed. Nothing bad will happen, though.

On the other hand, connecting with any other client will not set the limit, this may be a bit of a trap.

`pg_trgm` should really provide a config setting ...