# Difference between GiST and GIN index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

I am implementing a table that has a column with a data type of `tsvector` and I am trying to understand what index would be better to use?

GIN or GiST?

In looking through the [postgres documentation here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-indexes.html) I seem to get that:

- GiST is faster to update and build the index and less accurate than gin.
- GIN is slower to update and build the index but is more accurate.

OK, so why would anybody want a gist indexed field over gin? If gist could give you the wrong results? There must be some advantage (outside performance) on this.

Can anybody explain in layman's terms when I would want to use GIN vs. GiST?

Comment: *Always* provide your version of Postgres. GIN has received major improvements in Postgres 9.4

Answer (score 140, accepted):

I don't think I could explain it better than [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/textsearch-indexes.html) already does:

> In choosing which index type to use, GiST or GIN, consider these
> performance differences:
>
> - GIN index lookups are about three times faster than GiST
> - GIN indexes take about three times longer to build than GiST
> - GIN indexes are moderately slower to update than GiST indexes, but about 10 times slower if fast-update support was disabled [...]
> - GIN indexes are two-to-three times larger than GiST indexes

Link and quote refer to the manual for Postgres 9.4. Size and performance estimates seemed slightly outdated already. [With Postgres 9.4 the odds have shifted substantially **in favor of GIN**](http://www.sai.msu.su/%7Emegera/postgres//talks/329_PGCon2014-GIN.pdf).
The [release notes of Postgres 9.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/release-9-4.html#AEN119229) include:

> - Reduce GIN index size (Alexander Korotkov, Heikki Linnakangas) [...]
> - Improve speed of multi-key GIN lookups (Alexander Korotkov, Heikki
>   Linnakangas)

Size and performance estimates have since been removed from the manual.

Note that there are [special use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658515/multicolumn-index-on-3-fields-with-heterogenous-data-types/22675324#22675324) that require one or the other.

One thing you misunderstood: You ***never*** get wrong results with a GiST index. The index operates on hash values, which *can* lead to false positives in the index. This should only become relevant with a very big number of different words in your documents. False positives are eliminated after re-checking the actual row in any case. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-indexes.html):

> A GiST index is lossy, meaning that the index may produce false
> matches, and it is necessary to check the actual table row to
> eliminate such false matches. (**PostgreSQL does this automatically when needed.**)

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: I believe you meant "You never get wrong results with a GIN index", right?

Comment: @IamIC: You never get wrong results with either GIN or GiST. But I am specifically addressing GiST in the answer because the OP had a wrong impression there.

Comment: Understood. That makes sense.

Comment: If there are more reads than records in your table, you need to use GIN.

Comment: I think the point *GIN indexes are two-to-three times larger than GiST indexes* is not valid as I have tested with few large tables and found GiST index taking up more space than GIN and BTree indexes