# Postgres multi-column index (integer, boolean, and array)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-performance

I have a Postgres 9.4 database with a table like this:

```
| id | other_id | current | dn_ids                                | rank |
|----|----------|---------|---------------------------------------|------|
| 1  | 5        | F       | {123,234,345,456,111,222,333,444,555} | 1    |
| 2  | 7        | F       | {123,100,200,900,800,700,600,400,323} | 2    |
```

(update) I already have a couple indexes defined. Here is the `CREATE TABLE` syntax:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    other_id integer,
    rank integer,
    current boolean DEFAULT false,
    dn_ids integer[] DEFAULT '{}'::integer[]
);

CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE CACHE 1;

ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('mytable_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE INDEX ind_dn_ids ON mytable USING gin (dn_ids);
CREATE INDEX index_mytable_on_current ON mytable USING btree (current);
CREATE INDEX index_mytable_on_other_id ON mytable USING btree (other_id);
CREATE INDEX index_mytable_on_other_id_and_current ON mytable USING btree (other_id, current);
```

I need to optimize queries like this:

```sql
SELECT id, dn_ids
FROM mytable
WHERE other_id = 5 AND current = F AND NOT (ARRAY[100,200] && dn_ids)
ORDER BY rank ASC
LIMIT 500 OFFSET 1000
```

This query works fine, but I'm sure it could be much faster with smart indexing. There are about 250,000 rows in the table and I always have `current = F` as a predicate. The input array I'm comparing to the stored array will have 1-9 integers, as well. The `other_id` can vary. But generally, before limiting, the scan will match between 0-25,000 rows.

Here's an example `EXPLAIN`:

```
Limit  (cost=36944.53..36945.78 rows=500 width=65)
  ->  Sort  (cost=36942.03..37007.42 rows=26156 width=65)
        Sort Key: rank
        ->  Seq Scan on mytable  (cost=0.00..35431.42 rows=26156 width=65)
              Filter: ((NOT current) AND (NOT ('{-1,35257,35314}'::integer[] && dn_ids)) AND (other_id = 193))
```

Other answers on this site and the [Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) suggest it's possible to add a compound index to improve performance. I already have one on `[other_id, current]`. I've also read in various places that indexing can improve the performance of the `ORDER BY` in addition to the `WHERE` clause.

1. What's the right type of compound index to use for this query? I don't care about space at all.
2. Does it matter much how I order the terms in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Are any of your predicates immutable? Like: is it always `current = FALSE`? How many rows and how selective is each predicate? How many rows in the table and how many in the result (min /max / typical)? How many items in your arrays? Table definition: it would be much better to present a *standard form*: a complete `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d mytable` in psql. Query plan? ... There is ***more***, consider instructions in the [tag info of \[postgresql-performance\]](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: 1. I am only regularly selecting `current = FALSE` but the other parts vary.

2. There are about 250,000 rows in the table and I'm selecting anywhere from 0-25,0000 at a time, but with a `LIMIT` of a few hundred

3. There are up to 9 items in the stored array and I'm comparing 0-9 items in my input array

Comment: Please add your actual query. `LIMIT` changes its nature. And consider the rest of my points.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin. I just finished writing up my edit with the `CREATE TABLE` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What's the right type of compound index to use for this query? I don't care about space at all.

This depends on the complete situation. Either way, the GIN index you already have is most probably superior to a GiST index in your case:

- [Difference between GiST and GIN index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975517/difference-between-gist-and-gin-index/28976555#28976555)

You can combine either with `integer` columns once you install the additional module [btree_gin](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gin.html) (or [btree_gist](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/btree-gist.html), respectively).

- [Multicolumn index on 3 fields with heterogenous data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22658515/multicolumn-index-on-3-fields-with-heterogenous-data-types/22675324#22675324)

However, that does not cover the `boolean` data type, which typically doesn't make sense as index column to begin with. With just two (three incl. `NULL`) possible values it's not selective enough.

And a plain btree index is more efficient for `integer`. While a multicolumn btree index on two `integer` columns would certainly help, you'll have to test carefully if combining `(other_id, dn_ids)` in a multicolumn GIN index is worth more than it costs. Probably not. Postgres can combine multiple indexes in a bitmap index scan rather efficiently.

<strike>Finally, while indexes can be used for sorted output, this will probably not pay to apply for a query like you display (unless you select large parts of the table).</strike>
Not applicable to updated question.

Partial indexes *might* be an option. Other than that, **you already have all the indexes you need**.

I would drop the pointless index on the `boolean` column `current` completely, and the index on just `rank` is probably never used for this query.

> 2. Does it matter much how I order the terms in the `WHERE` clause?

The order of `WHERE` conditions is completely irrelevant.

#### Addendum after question update

The utility of indexes is bound to **selective** criteria. If more than roughly 5 % (depends on various factors) of the table are selected, a sequential scan of the whole table is typically faster than dealing with the overhead on any indexes - except for **pre-sorting output**, that's the one thing an index is still good for in such cases.

For a query that fetches **25,000 of 250,000** rows, indexes are mostly just for that - which gets all the more interesting if you attach a **`LIMIT`** clause. Postgres can stop fetching rows from an index once the `LIMIT` is satisfied.

Be aware that Postgres always needs to read `OFFSET` + `LIMIT` rows, so performance deteriorate with the sum of both.

Even with your added information, much of what's relevant is still in the dark. I am going to **assume** that:

1. Your predicate `NOT (ARRAY[100,200] && dn_ids)` is ***not*** very selective. Ruling out 1 to 10 ID values should typically retain the majority of rows unless you have very few distinct elements in `dn_ids`.
2. The most selective predicate is `other_id = 5`.
3. A substantial part of the rows is eliminated with `NOT current`.
   <sub>Aside: <strike>`current = F`</strike> isn't valid syntax in standard Postgres. Must be `NOT current` or `current = FALSE`;</sub>

While a GIN index would be great to identify *few* rows with matching arrays faster than any other index type, this seems hardly relevant for your query. My best guess is this **partial, multicolumn btree index**:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON mytable (other_id, rank, dn_ids)
WHERE NOT current;
```

The array column `dn_ids` in a btree index cannot support the `&&` operator, I just include it to allow [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) and filter rows before accessing the heap (the table). May even be faster without `dn_ids` in the index:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON mytable (other_id, rank) WHERE NOT current;
```

GiST indexes may become more interesting in [Postgres 9.5 due to this new feature](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/interactive/release-9-5.html#AEN125714):

> Allow GiST indexes to perform index-only scans (Anastasia Lubennikova,
>   Heikki Linnakangas, Andreas Karlsson)

Aside: [`current` is a reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) in standard SQL, even if it's allowed as identifier in Postgres.
Aside 2: I assume `id` is an actual `serial` column with the column default set. Just creating a sequence like you demonstrate, would do nothing.

- [Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up. I've replaced my indexes with your partial composite index as suggested and am seeing a definite speed-up. I also benchmarked that index and various combinations of others on a random sample of queries. Interestingly, the presence of `rank` and `other_id` make the biggest improvements, while `dn_ids` and the partial index on `current` making smaller improvements.

Comment: @Devin: Usefulness of a partial index mainly depends on the share of rows excluded by the index condition - the more the merrier. Typically, repeated query execution (as soon as the index is cached) is only improved slightly, the depth of a btree index grows very slowly. The first invocation can make a bigger difference, and the smaller memory footprint increases chances to stay in cache. Finally, the index is only updated for included rows (cheaper writes).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately I don't think you can combine a BTree and a GIN/GIST index into a single compound index, so the planner is going to have to choose between using the `other_id` index or the `dn_ids` index.  One advantage of using other_id, as you pointed out, is that you could use a multicolumn index to improve the sort performance.  The way you would do this would be

```
 CREATE INDEX index_mytable_on_other_id_and_current
           ON mytable (other_id, rank) WHERE current = F;
```

This is using a partial index, and will allow you to skip the sort step when you are sorting by rank and querying on other_id.

Depending on the cardinality of other_id, the only benefit of this might be the sorting.  Because your plan has a LIMIT clause, it's difficult to tell.  SEQ scans can be the fastest option if you're using > 1/5 of the table, especially if you're using a standard HDD instead of solid state.  If you're planner insists on SEQ scanning when you know an IDX scan is faster (you've tested with `enable_seqscan false`, you may want to try fine tuning your `random_page_cost` or `effective_cache_size`.

Finally, I'd recomment *not* keeping all of these indexes.  Find the ones you need, and cull the rest.  Indexes cause huge performance degradation in inserts (especially mutli-column and GIN/GIST indexes).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest index for your query is `mytable(other_id, current)`.  This handles the first two conditions.  This would be a normal b-tree type index.

You can satisfy the array condition using a GIST index on `mytable(dn_ids)`.

However, I don't think you can mix the different data types in one index, at least not without extensions.