# Optimal Postgres text index for LIKE query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, sql-like, gwt-gin

Using Postgres 9.5, I have a table `addresses`.

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
    id        integer PRIMARY KEY,
    address   text
);
```

In that table I have 7.5 million rows. Example:

`1, "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue NW, Washington, DC, 20500"`

I'm using this table for an autosuggest search in my application so I need to use this type of query:

```
SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE address LIKE '123 Main St%';
```

I created this index:

```
CREATE INDEX address_idx ON addresses (address);
```

But the problem is it's taking around 1 sec which is too slow.

Here's the query plan:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE address LIKE '123 Main St%';
----
Seq Scan on addresses  (cost=0.00..161309.76 rows=740 width=41)
  Filter: (address ~~ '123 Main St%'::text)
```

I tried creating a few types of `gin` indexes but they either had no effect or made the query slower. I'm not sure if I was using them correctly though.

Any ideas on how to create an index that's optimized for this kind of query?

---

EDIT

The best solution found so far is to use a text range scan:

```
SELECT *
FROM addresses
WHERE address >= '123 Main St' AND
      address <= concat('123 Main St', 'z');
```

Comment: Will this always be a prefix search? Then you can try WHERE address BETWEEN '123 Main St' AND '123 Main Su'. That should produce a range scan on the index.

Comment: The index should work fine for this query.  Perhaps there is an incompatibility with the text types somehow that prevents the use of the index.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks! Using BETWEEN produces the same results as the LIKE query and reduced the time down to 13ms. To answer your question, yes this will always be a prefix search. The only thing I don't like about this method is I'll have to come up with the next letter in the alphabet or the next number instead of using a wildcard symbol. Is there any other way to produce a range scan without having to write in that kind of logic?

Comment: Ideally, the query planner should have detected the prefix search and transformed it into a BETWEEN query. And even if not, worst case should have been an index scan (instead of a table scan) -- not that that would have been any faster in this case.

Answer (score 5):

This is an elaboration on the `between` method and too long for a comment.

If you are using standard ASCII characters, you can use the tilde-trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM addresses
WHERE address >= '123 Main St' AND
      address <= concat('123 Main St', '~');
```

Tilde has a larger ASCII value than other characters.

I do note that Postgres should use the index for the `LIKE` query as well.  My guess is that the problem is something to do with compatibility of the types.  Perhaps if you converted the pattern to a `varchar()`, Postgres would use the index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Pretty clever indeed but I'm running into trouble with that query: `ERROR: argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text - on line 4`. I'm using standard ASCII characters btw. Could you elaborate on what you mean by convert the pattern to a varchar()? Do you mean the column?

Comment: @Tyler . . . That might be due to operator precedence.

Comment: Removing the double pipe and adding the tilde, i.e. '123 Main St~', solves the error but returns no results. I also tried '123 Main S~' which didn't work. Referencing the ASCII table, it seems like 'z' is the largest ASCII value character that I can use to return any results. Edit: concat('123 Main St', 'z') works.

Comment: @Tyler . . . Interesting.  The tilde has worked for me in other contexts.  At least the `z` works, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think the range scan with your concat suggestion is the best solution!

Comment: @GordonLinoff `SELECT * FROM addresses WHERE address LIKE '%123 Main St%'; ` What if wild card is before and after the `123 Main St` in this Case. What should I do to make the scan faster

Comment: @vinieth . . . That would be a different question.  You should investigate GIN and related indexes and  if you need more help, ask a new question as a *question*.

Comment: For me z works out of the box. ~ works when I use ~>=~ instead of >=. It can also use a text_pattern_ops index, although z and >= is about as fast for me.

Answer (score 4):

Three things you could try:

1. If your database is on '`C`' locale (which you can check with `\l` on the `psql` prompt) then the regular `Btree` indexes should help in optimizing a `LIKE 'abc%'` type of query.
2. If not, you could try using a suitable operator class when creating the `Btree` index. For e.g. `CREATE INDEX tbl_col_text_pattern_ops_idx ON tbl(col text_pattern_ops);`
3. If that doesn't work, you could also try using the `GiST / GIN`, more detailing for which is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975517/difference-between-gist-and-gin-index/28976555#28976555).

If you'd like to know more you should read Erwin's StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations#answer-13452528), that details how different Postgres indexes work with `LIKE` / `ILIKE`.