# PostgreSQL: pg_trgm full-text search with jsonb columns?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with a jsonb column where I store variable data. I would like to search this column and also find fragments (leading or trailing whitespace). I think I know how to do this with text columns but cannot wrap my head around how to achieve this with `jsonb` columns.

There are two scenarios that I would like to achieve:

1. Search a specific key inside the jsonb column only (for example
   `data->>company`)
2. Search the whole `jsonb` column

For text columns I generate [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975517/difference-between-a-gist-index-and-gin-index/28976555#28976555) indexes using [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html).

Install extension pg_trgm:

```
CREATE extension if not exists pg_trgm;
```

Create table & index:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (
    col_text  text,
    col_json  jsonb
);

CREATE INDEX table_col_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gin (col_text gin_trgm_ops);
```

Example query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col_text LIKE '%foo%';   -- leading wildcard
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col_text ILIKE '%foo%';  -- works case insensitive as well
```

Trying the same with the jsonb column fails. If I try to index the whole column

```
CREATE INDEX table_col_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gin (col_json gin_trgm_ops);
```

I get the error

```
ERROR (datatype_mismatch): operator class "gin_trgm_ops" does not accept data type jsonb
```

(Which makes sense). If I try to index just one key of the jsonb column I also receive an error:

```
CREATE INDEX table_col_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gin (col_json->>company gin_trgm_ops);
```

Error:

```
ERROR (syntax_error): syntax error at or near "->>"
```

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528) by [@erwin-brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) as a reference. Any help is highly appreciated (and no, I don't want to implement Elasticsearch as of now :) ).

---

**Edit:** Creating the index like this actually works:

```
CREATE INDEX table_col_trgm_idx ON tbl USING gin ((col_json->>'company') gin_trgm_ops);
```

And querying it also doesn't lead to an error:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col_json->>'company' LIKE '%foo%';
```

But the result is always **empty**.

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: @Michas But do you also get results?

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154164/postgresql-pg-trgm-full-text-search-with-jsonb-columns

Comment: Sorry. Bit desperate. Deleted the other post

Comment: @ØleBjarnstroem I get results and the query plan use the index. Do You have entities in table?

Comment: I have entries. I search for a value that is in the database. And I even ran `REINDEX TABLE tbl;` just to make sure. Result is still 0 rows...

Comment: @Michas: I just started to wonder that maybe the data in my column is malformed since I use postgresql together with Elixir and Ecto seems to have a weird way of using the jsonb column...

Comment: @ØleBjarnstroem Try `SELECT col_json::text FROM tbl LIMIT 10;` I hope this will be enough to debug data.

Comment: I get this result: `"{\"website\":\"Website Content\",\"company\":\"Company Content\"}` - Is it possible that the content was escaped by Elixir and not strictly jsonb?

Comment: Case closed. I was using a custom Ecto DataType on this column, encoding and decoding content with Poison. This was due to the fact that Ecto back then didn't support jsonb and this was a (bad) way to implement it. I will try with a regular jsonb column and report back. Thank you for your help.