# Index for comparing to beginning of every word in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

So I have a table

```
id | name            | gender
---+-----------------+-------
0  | Markus Meskanen | M
1  | Jack Jackson    | M
2  | Jane Jackson    | F
```

And I've created an index

```
CREATE INDEX people_name_idx ON people (LOWER(name));
```

And then I query with

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE LOWER('Jack%');
```

Where `%(name)s` is the user's input. However, it now matches only to the beginning of the whole column, but I'd like it to match to the beginning of any of the words. I'd prefer not to use `'%Jack%'` since it would also result into invalid results from the middle of the word.

Is there a way to create an index so that each word gets a separate row?

**Edit:** If the name is something long like `'Michael Jackson's First Son Bob'` it should match to the beginning of any of the words, i.e. `Mich` would match to `Michael` and `Fir` would match to `First` but `ackson` wouldn't match to anything since it's not from the beginning.

**Edit 2:** And we have 3 million rows so performance is an issue, thus I'm looking at indexes mostly.

Comment: the shortest change would be `lower('% Jack %')` to hit Jack in text, but using regular expressions here seems reasonable

Comment: What happens if someone has a middle name?

Comment: I don't think you need to convert it to lowercase.

Comment: @VaoTsun That wouldn't find `Jack Jackson` since he's got no space in front of his name, or would it find `Jane Jackson` since she's got no space after her surname

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It should match it just like first and last names

Comment: I wonder why no one mentioned yet, but the [`pg_trgm` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) *is* what you are looking for. Its `gist_trgm_ops` and `gin_trgm_ops` based indexes enhances `LIKE`, `ILIKE`, `~` and `~*` queries (you don't have to create a `LOWER(...)` expression-based index for it).

Comment: @pozs You might wanna add an answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pg_trgm` module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html) does exactly what you want.

You need to create either:

```
CREATE INDEX people_name_idx ON people USING GIST (name gist_trgm_ops);
```

Or:

```
CREATE INDEX people_name_idx ON people USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

[See the difference here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975517/difference-between-gist-and-gin-index)

After that, these queries could use one of the indexes above:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ILIKE '%Jack%';
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ~* '\mJack';
```

As [@GordonLinoff answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41956624/1499698), [full text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) is also capable of searching by prefix matches. But FTS is not designed to do that efficiently, it is best in matching lexemes. Though if you want to achieve the best performace, I advise you to give it a try too & measure each. In FTS, your query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE to_tsvector('english', name) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'Jack:*');
```

**Note**: however if your query filter (`Jack`) comes from user input, both of these queries above needs some protection (i.e. in the `ILIKE` one you need to escape `%` and `_` characters, in the regexp one you need to escape a lot more, and in the FTS one, well you'll need to parse the query with some parser & generate a valid FTS' `tsquery` query, because `to_tsquery()` will give you an error if its parameter is not valid. And in `plainto_tsquery()` you cannot use a prefix matching query).

**Note 2**: the regexp variant with `name ~* '\mJack'` will work best with english names. If you want to use the whole range of unicode (i.e. you want to use characters, like `æ`), you'll need a slightly different pattern. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name ~* '(^|\s|,)Jack';
```

This will work with most of the names, plus this will work like a real prefix match with some old names too, like `O'Brian`.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres has two index types to help with full text searches:  GIN and GIST indexes (and I think GIN is the more commonly used one).

There is a brief overview of the indexes in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/textsearch-indexes.html).  There is more extensive documentation for each index class, as well as plenty of blogs on the subject ([here](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/) is one and [here](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/exploring-postgres-gin-index) is another).

These can speed up the searches that you are trying to do.

Comment: Hmm this seems nice, i'll have to look further into it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regex expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-MATCHING-RULES) to find text inside name:

```
create table ci(id int, name text);

insert into ci values
(1, 'John McEnroe Blackbird Petrus'),
(2, 'Michael Jackson and Blade');

select id, name
from ci
where name ~ 'Pe+'
;
```

Returns:

```
    1   John McEnroe Blackbird Petrus
```

Or can use something similar `where substring(name, <regex exp>) is not null`

Check it here: http://rextester.com/LHA16094

Answer (score -1):

If you know that the words are space separated, You can do

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE name LIKE LOWER('Jack%') or  name LIKE LOWER(' Jack%')  ;
```

For more control you can use RegEx with MySQl

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: The OP is using Postgres, not MySQL.

Comment: This doesn't utilize indexing. I have 3,000,000+ rows of data, using `LIKE LOWER('% Jack%')` would be extremely slow.