# If i have a string can I see if there are records with sub strings

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

If I have a string 'this is a goodish string'
And I have three records in the database

1, "good"
2, "fart"
3, "this"

is there a way to do a lookup for records that are substrings of my source..

I ask because I have a black_list table that contains entries that I never want to allow my user to store.  Like if they wanted to store www.google.com, and I had "google" in my black list, I'd get a positive result from exists, and know to not let them..

I'll keep digging and I might post my answer here, but it's an interesting thing to figure out.  I'd rather do it in the DB layer than in the ruby/rails layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to match whole words, this is going to be **considerably faster** with a bigger table because it can use an index on `entry` (unlike your solution, where the predicate is not [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)):

### Simple

Assuming white space as word separator (`\s+`).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   black_list 
JOIN   regexp_split_to_table('the task description', '\s+') entry USING (entry)
```

### Advanced

For more specific needs, you can tailor the words you extract:

Split words (as defined by the POSIX standard) at `\m`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)

> ```
> matches only at the beginning of a word
> ```

Remove leading, trailing or *all* characters you want to ignore. Since we split at the *beginning* of words, trailing characters may be enough.

Finally cast to lower case - assuming lower case entries in `black_list`:

#### Basic and fast

Split words and trim given trailing characters:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   black_list 
JOIN  (
   SELECT rtrim(w, ' /\,.-') AS entry -- add more?
   FROM   regexp_split_to_table('Oh - my, a4b smurf-village in/out.', '\m') w
   ) w USING (entry);
```

#### Thorough

Split words, remove *all* non-word characters and convert to lower case:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   black_list 
JOIN  (
   SELECT lower(regexp_replace(w, '\W+', '')) AS entry
   FROM   regexp_split_to_table('Oh - my, a4b smurf-village in/out.', '\m') w
   ) w USING (entry);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/4489)

### Beyond

You can take it one step further and test for **similarity** to also catch typos. But you have to weigh alpha against beta error (incorrectly excluding legal words).

```sql
SELECT set_limit(0.9); -- high example value

SELECT *
FROM   black_list b
JOIN  (
   SELECT lower(regexp_replace(w, '\W+', '')) AS entry
   FROM   regexp_split_to_table('Oh - my, a4b smurf-village in/out.', '\m') w
   ) w ON b.entry % w.entry
```

The `%` operator requires the additional module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). Details:

- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Comment: This is a great answer.. sadly I need to match smurf-village and smurfs with an entry of smurf.  Happily my entries will be likely stay under a hundred.  We're only trying to create a black list for really persistent offenders of a sit policy. Wack-a-mole, but we punish rather well.

Comment: Oh.. +1, because you're totally right.. it would be faster for whole word entries.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

It took far less time than I thought.. mostly because I just tried out different things.

```
select * from black_list 
where 'this is the task description' like concat('%', entry, '%')
```

For the rails dev's out there

```
 scope :part_of, ->(source) { where("? like concat('%', entry, '%')", source) }


 BlackList.part_of('this is a test fire').exists?
 BlackList.part_of(task.description).exists?
```