# PostgreSQL '%' operator

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, operators

Does anyone know what is the effect of `%` operator on `varchar`?

I found this query in a project and don't really know what it is doing:

```
SELECT * FROM Location l where l.name % :param;
```

I supposed that it has the same effect that:

```
SELECT * FROM Location l where l.name LIKE '%:param%'
```

But I didn't find the explanation on PostgreSQL documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`%`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) is the "similarity" operator, provided by the [additional module **pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html).

It takes `text` (or other string types) as left and right operand and returns `boolean`: `true` if both operands are similar enough, `false` if not. The threshold is set with the GUC parameter `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`.

Related:

- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

Not to be confused with the [modulo operator **`%`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE). Same symbol, but the mathematical operator takes *numeric* types as left and right operand.

In Postgres, operators are defined by the operator name (like `%`) plus left and right operands. Gory details in the manual chapter [Operator Type Resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-oper.html). The casual user hardly needs to know any of this. Typically, it just works.

Related:

- [Can PostgreSQL index array columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4058731/can-postgresql-index-array-columns/29245753#29245753)

Comment: oh ok... I'm trying to make some unit tests on an H2 in-memory database with Postgresql mode. I reproduced the similarity function that is not natively supported by H2 but i don't know if i could reproduce the operator...

Comment: @MatthieuSaleta: Follow [the link to the manual I provided](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html). There is a description of what it does exactly.