# Why is postgres trigram word_similarity function not using a gin index?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, trigram

The postgres [trigram documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/pgtrgm.html) states:

> The pg_trgm module provides GiST and GIN index operator classes that allow you to create an index over a text column for the purpose of very fast similarity searches. These index types support the above-described similarity operators, and additionally support trigram-based index searches for LIKE, ILIKE, ~ and ~* queries.

and shows the following example:

```sql
SELECT t, word_similarity('word', t) AS sml
  FROM test_trgm
  WHERE 'word' <% t
  ORDER BY sml DESC, t;
```

Awesome!

However, when running the following query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM place 
WHERE word_similarity(place.name, '__SOME_STRING__') > 0.5
```

The index that was created is not being used.

However, when using `ILIKE` or the `%>` operators, it does seem that the index is being used. Why is the index not used on the `word_similarity` function?

Answer (score 6):

According to this [postgres forum response](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20171021120104.GA1563%40arthur.localdomain)

> PostgreSQL doesn't use index scan with functions within WHERE clause. So
>   you always need to use operators instead. You can try <% operator and
>   pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold variable:
>
> =# SET pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold TO 0.1;
>
> =# SELECT name, popularity
>       FROM temp.items3_v
>           ,(values ('some phrase'::text)) consts(input)
>       WHERE input <% name
>       ORDER BY 2, input <<-> name;

So, the query can be updated to use the index as follows:

```sql
SET pg_trgm.word_similarity_threshold TO 0.1;
SELECT * 
FROM place 
WHERE place.name <<-> '__SOME_STRING__';
```

---

**Warning**: the operator only uses the index with only one version of the commutator pair. I.e., it only used the index in the case `<<->` and not the case `<->>`. [This stack overflow q/a post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/243951/75296) looks like it gives a reasonable explanation as to why:

> These are different operations, and only one of them is supported by the index.