# Real number comparison for trigram similarity

Tags: sql, postgresql, trigram, pg-trgm

I am implementing trigram similarity for word matching in column `comum1`. `similarity()` returns `real`. I have converted *0.01* to `real` and rounded to 2 decimal digits. Though there are rank values greater than 0.01, I get no results on screen. If I remove the `WHERE` condition, lots of results are available. Kindly guide me how to overcome this issue.

```
SELECT *,ROUND(similarity(comum1,"Search_word"),2) AS rank
FROM schema.table
WHERE rank >= round(0.01::real,2)
```

I have also converted both numbers to `numeric` and compared, but that also didn't work:

```
SELECT *,ROUND(similarity(comum1,"Search_word")::NUMERIC,2) AS rank
FROM schema.table
WHERE rank >= round(0.01::NUMERIC,2)
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Does `rank >= 0.01` not work?

Comment: @Bohemian: That shouldn't work, either.

Comment: rank >= 0.01 is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause can only reference ***input*** column names, coming from the underlying table(s). `rank` in your example is the column alias for a result - an *output* column name.

So your statement is illegal and should return with an error message - unless you have another column named `rank` in `schema.table`, in which case you shot yourself in the foot. I would think twice before introducing such a naming collision, while I am not completely firm with SQL syntax.

And [`round()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) with a second parameter is not defined for `real`, you would need to cast to `numeric` like you tried. Another reason your first query is illegal.

Also, the double-quotes around `"Search_word"` are highly suspicious. If that's supposed to be a string literal, you need single quotes:  `'Search_word'`.

This should work:

```sql
SELECT *, round(similarity(comum1,'Search_word')::numeric,2) AS rank
FROM   schema.table
WHERE  similarity(comum1, 'Search_word') > 0.01;
```

But it's still pretty useless as it fails to make use of trigram indexes. Do this instead:

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.01;  -- set once
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   schema.table
WHERE  comum1 % 'Search_word';
```

See:

- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)

That said, a similarity of *0.01* is almost **no** similarity. Typically, you need a much higher threshold.

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Your help is always take me a step forward. I deeply appreciate your all comments.