# How to improve or speed up Postgres query with pg_trgm?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, pg-trgm

Are there any additional steps I can take to speed up query execution?

I have a table with more than 100m rows and I need to do search for matching strings. For that I checked two options:

1. Compare text with to_tsvector `@@` (to_tsquery or plainto_tsquery)
   This works very fast (under 1s on all data) but it has some problems with finding text similarity
2. Compare text with pg_trgm similarity
   This works fine on text comparison but works bad on large amount of data.

I found that I can use indexes to improve performance.
For my GiST index I tried to increase `siglen` from small number to 2024, but for some reason Postgres uses `512` and not higher.

```
CREATE INDEX trgm_idx_512_gg ON table USING GIST (name gist_trgm_ops(siglen=512));
```

Query:

```
SELECT name, similarity(name, 'ноутбук MSI GF63 Thin 10SC 086XKR 9S7 16R512 086') as sm
FROM table
WHERE name % 'ноутбук MSI GF63 Thin 10SC 086XKR 9S7 16R512 086'
```

`EXPLAIN` output:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on table (cost=1632.01..40051.57 rows=9737 width=126)
  Recheck Cond: ((name)::text % 'ноутбук MSI GF63 Thin 10SC 086XKR 9S7 16R512 086'::text)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_512_gg  (cost=0.00..1629.57 rows=9737 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((name)::text % 'ноутбук MSI GF63 Thin 10SC 086XKR 9S7 16R512 086'::text)
```

Execution time was about 120 sec.

#### Question

How can I improve or speed up query? Maybe I need to use a different approach or just add something else?

Output for `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` (searching for a different name so that the search is completely new and not from the cache):

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on table (cost=1632.01..40051.57 rows=9737 width=126) (actual time=159119.258..159960.251 rows=5645 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((name)::text % 'Чехол на realme C25s / Реалми Ц25с c рисунком / прозрачный с принтом, Andy&Paul'::text)
  Heap Blocks: exact=3795
  Buffers: shared read=1289378
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trgm_idx_512_gg  (cost=0.00..1629.57 rows=9737 width=0) (actual time=159118.616..159118.616 rows=5645 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((name)::text % 'Чехол на realme C25s / Реалми Ц25с c рисунком / прозрачный с принтом, Andy&Paul'::text)
        Buffers: shared read=1285583
Planning:
  Buffers: shared read=5
Planning Time: 4.063 ms
Execution Time: 159961.121 ms
```

I also created a GIN index (but Postgres kept using the GiST):

```
CREATE INDEX gin_gg ON table USING GIN (name gin_trgm_ops);
```

Size: 12 GB.

GIST index: 31GB

Comment: Post the plan using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` not just `EXPLAIN`.  Did you try to index with GIN rather than GiST?

Comment: Disclose your version of Postgres, and define "similarity" more closely. I see 5645 result rows in your plan, and no sort order. Trigram similarity has an adjustable similarity threshold. How many results and/or how similar should it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trigram GiST index with `siglen=512` on 100m rows is very large, and will probably never be cached efficiently. (Default is `siglen=12` i.e. 12 bytes.) What makes you think this large signature would be a good choice? [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.8)

> Longer signatures lead to a more precise search (scanning a smaller fraction of the index and fewer heap pages), at the cost of a larger index.

Looks like you went overboard with the size.

I have better experience with a trigram GIN indexes, especially in current versions of Postgres. If the query planner is confused by the existence of an additional GiST index, you'll have to remove that one, to test results with the GIN index.

But first, to get a size comparison, look at the output of:

```sql
SELECT i.indexrelid::regclass::text AS idx
     , pg_get_indexdef(i.indexrelid) AS idx_def
     , pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(i.indexrelid)) AS idx_size
FROM   pg_class t
JOIN   pg_index i ON i.indrelid = t.oid
WHERE  t.oid = 'public.tbl'::regclass  -- your table name here!
ORDER  BY 1;
```

(Ideally, add the result to the questions.)

Your query plan shows vast amounts of `Buffers: shared read` for index and main relation (heap). So nothing was found in cache. The key to better performance will be to read fewer data pages to satisfy your queries, and more of them from cache: `hit` instead of `read` in the query plan.

Reducing the size of table and indexes helps in this reagard.

The selectivity of the trigram similarity operator `%` is set by the [customized option `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.6). The default `0.3` is rather lax and allows many hits. A higher similarity threshold will filter fewer (better matching) result rows. What do you do with `rows=5645` result rows anyway? Try:

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.5;  -- or higher
```

Then retry your query.
See:

- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)
- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

The latest version or Postgres, better server configuration and more RAM can also help in this regard. You disclosed no information about either of these.

Comment: `What makes you think this large signature would be a good choice?` I thought that if siglen will be higher than results would be return faster. But as I see, it is not like that, Cna You add some explanation about that? @Erwin Brandstetter

Comment: @Dmiich: longer signature will narrow down index hits, but at the cost of a larger index. Index size quickly becomes much more important, and you clearly missed the sweet spot, especially since you obviously don't have enough RAM to cache your data. I added a quote from the manual.

Comment: Can you please show resulting index sizes in your question? The result of the query I provided.

Comment: Size and definition of GIN and GiST index are of interest. Shouldn't be compromising any confidentiality. You can obfuscate names according to the rest of your post.

Comment: Edited question. But there is only GIN index because after Your answer I deleted GIST so postgres will use a GIN index

Comment: I did advise: *"But first, to get a size comparison, look at the output of:"* :( Do you remember the size of the GiST index?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I will create this GIST index. After it will be done, I will update the answer

Comment: Will be expensive to recreate. Either way: Do you get faster results already with the GIN index? Any luck with a higher threshold? And did you see the other requests in my comment? Gotta run now ...

Comment: Expensive to create, but now I am wondering whatsize it will be :), GIN is working fster  and threshold is helping a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your indexes are correct, besides that, here are some strategies in order of importance according to this specific case to tune your query performance:

- In your execution plan can be noticed that **buffers are being read
  instead of hit** (means that data is missing from prostgres buffer
  cache and is read from disk) see  [Using buffers for query
  optimization](https://www.pgmustard.com/blog/using-postgres-buffers-for-query-optimization).

  Issue a  `SELECT setting, unit FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'shared_buffers';`  to see the size of your database buffers (that
  number must be mutiplied by unit, 80k usually to see actual size in
  kbs).

  It's recommended 25% of server's RAM for buffers, and usually
  is left on it's defult value, that is 16384 * 8kb = 128Mb,  but
  should be adapt to the situation. In tests i have seen a slight
  improvement (not much when storage is in SSDs) in query performance, you can change this parameter in postgresql.conf file and a database restart is
  required.
- Peform a `vacuum verbose analyze <table>;` to check if there is data
  blocked by pending transactions (dead rows blocked) and at the same
  time execute a vacuum analyze operation, the PostgreSQL query planner
  relies on statistical information about the contents of tables in
  order to generate good plans for queries. These statistics are
  gathered by the ANALYZE command, which can be invoked by itself or as
  an optional step in VACUUM. It is important to have reasonably
  accurate statistics, otherwise poor choices of plans might degrade
  database performance, see
  [vaccuming](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html).

  For many installations, it is sufficient to let vacuuming be
  performed by the autovacuum daemon, but some database administrators
  will want to supplement or replace the daemon's activities with
  manually-managed VACUUM commands, which typically are executed
  according to a schedule by cron or Task Scheduler scripts. This
  updates the visibility map, which speeds up index-only scans (which
  in your case doesn't fully apply, because mainly, data is obtained by
  heap scan).
- Could execute a `cluster <table> using <index>;` (when database is
  out of production because its a blocking method) to reorganize data
  for faster access, however for this use case i don't see performance
  improvement, see [sql-cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html).

Comment: If there's 100m rows, they might need to reconfigure autovacuum to be more aggressive.