# Querying a custom postgresql parameter with SELECT statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, settings

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288823), it was asked how to query a postgresql runtime parameter (e.g. `SHOW search_path;`) using a SELECT query. In the answer, it was suggested to use

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'search_path';
```

This works great, but how can this be done for custom parameters defined in an extension? (See docs about  [Customized Options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-custom.html)).

Example:

```
SET abc.my_var = 1;
SHOW abc.my_var;
```

outputs

```
1
```

but

```
SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'abc.my_var';
```

returns no rows. Is there some other table/view I can query for my custom parameter using a SELECT statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the function `current_setting()`

```
SELECT current_setting('abc.my_var');
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET