# How do I use variables in throwaway queries in pgAdmin3 1.8.4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

**Important**: I am constrained to pgAdmin 1.8.4. It's very old (2008). Using a newer version results in many errors because the database I'm talking to is old and not updated. The other team members use this version of pgAdmin. `"PostgreSQL 8.3.6 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)"`

Say I want to run this query for 8 different tables:

```
SELECT to_char(rowlastupdated, 'YYYY-MM'), count(rowlastupdated)
FROM abc.foo
WHERE
  (
    rowlastupdated::TIMESTAMP >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00' :: TIMESTAMP
  AND (rowlastupdated::TIMESTAMP <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59' :: TIMESTAMP)
   )
group by  to_char(rowlastupdated, 'YYYY-MM')
  ;

... repeat 7 times
```

Rather than find/replacing every time I want to change the start date (`'2012-01-01 00:00:00'`), I'd like to make it a variable. In SQL Server I'd set that date as `DECLARE @startDate varchar(30); SET @startDate = '2012-01-01 00:00:00'` and use the variable in my query (with some CAST probably).

I can't figure out how to do this in pgAdmin. The [PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/plpgsql-declarations.html) say I can do:

```
url varchar := 'http://example.com';
```

but that line just errors out in pgAdmin queries:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "url"
LINE 1: url varchar := 'http://example.com';
```

How can I declare a string in one place and then use it in many queries in pgAdmin? I don't want to create a function because these queries are one-time use, effectively and I don't want to clutter up the database with functions that I forgot to delete.

Comment: use do https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-do.html

Comment: Can't, too new: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "DO"`; that's in PG 9+ and I'm in 8.

Comment: For example try [this Q and A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14179335/593144)

Comment: Can you use [pgScript](https://www.pgadmin.org/gitrepo/pgadmin3-dev/docs/en_US/_build/html/pgscript.html) with your version?

Comment: No :( The pgScript button (in the newer versions) is "Execute and save to file" in the old version