# Sample Query to show Cardinality estimation error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a project using PostgreSQL9.3. I was using the below query to show how selectivity estimation errors can lead to multi-fold increase in query execution time on TPC-H workload using PostgreSQL8.3.

```
select 
    n_name, 
    sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount)) as revenue 
from 
    customer, 
    orders, 
    lineitem, 
    supplier, 
    nation,
    region 
where 
    c_custkey = o_custkey 
    and l_orderkey = o_orderkey 
    and l_suppkey = s_suppkey   
    and c_nationkey = s_nationkey 
    and s_nationkey = n_nationkey 
    and n_regionkey = r_regionkey 
    and (r_name='ASIA' or r_name='AFRICA') 
    and o_orderdate >= date '1994-01-01' 
    and o_orderdate < date '1994-01-01' + interval '1 year' 
    and l_shipdate <= l_receiptdate 
    and l_commitdate <= l_shipdate + integer '90' 
    and l_extendedprice <= 20000 
    and c_name like '%r#00%' 
    and c_acctbal <=2400 
group by 
    n_name 
order by    
    revenue desc
```

The problem was that PostgreSQL8.3 was choosing a plan which involves lot of NestedLoop joins since selectivity estimation on lineitem and customer were wrong by big margin. I think this was majorly due to LIKE pattern matching. But the optimal plan should have been using Hash Joins.

Recently I upgraded to PostgreSQL9.3 for my Project and observed that the above query no longer gives a bad plan. I spent some amount of time trying to find a query with large **cardinality estimation error** on TPC-H 1GB data with no success till now. Does any PostgreSQL geeks know some off the shelf query on TPC-H benchmark or any query to show cardinality estimation error in PostgreSQL9.3

Comment: Answer to your question is unfortunately no, though I have come across them.  You're using pre ansi-92 standards for joins...I remember back in 8.x days that I'd occasionally get really poor execution plans while re-writing to ansi-92 syntax improved it...I think 9.3 improved it's ability to handle this syntax

Comment: Question might be a good candidate for dba.SE.

Comment: @Twelfth: For the Postgres query planner, `WHERE` clauses and `INNER JOIN` clauses are all the same internally, AFAIK. Explicit join syntax is still much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I thought the same as well, but I've had some really screwy execution plans come up on the where clause joins before...it was years ago though.

Comment: @Twelfth: I supplied an answer addressing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to answer the [comment by @Twelfth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002263/sample-query-to-show-cardinality-estimation-error-in-postgresql/25002962#comment38874666_25002263) as well as the question itself.

[Three quotes from this chapter in the manual:

"**Controlling the Planner with Explicit `JOIN` Clauses**"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/explicit-joins.html)

> Explicit inner join syntax (`INNER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`, or unadorned `JOIN`)
>   is **semantically the same** as listing the input relations in `FROM`, so it
>   does not constrain the join order.

...

> To force the planner to follow the join order laid out by explicit
>   `JOIN`s, set the `join_collapse_limit` run-time parameter to 1. (Other
>   possible values are discussed below.)

...

> Constraining the planner's search in this way is a useful technique
>   both for reducing planning time and for **directing the planner to a
>   good query plan**.

Bold emphasis mine. Conversely, you can abuse the same to direct the query planner to a *bad* query plan for your testing purposes. Read the whole manual page. It should be instrumental.

Also, you can force nested loops by [disabling alternative methods](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-ENABLE) one by one (best in your session only). Like:

```
SET enable_hashjoin = off;
```

Etc.
About checking and setting parameters:

- [Query a parameter (postgresql.conf setting) like "max_connections"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288823/query-a-parameter-postgresql-conf-setting-like-max-connections/8288860#8288860)

### Force actual estimation errors

One obvious way would be to disable [autovacuum](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) and add / remove rows from the table. Then the query planner is working with outdated statistics. Note that some other commands update statistics as well.

Statistics are stored in the catalog tables `pg_class` and `pg_statistics`.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'mytable'::regclass;
SELECT * FROM pg_statistic WHERE starelid = 'mytable'::regclass;
```

This leads me to another option. You could forge entries in these two tables. Superuser privileges required.
You don't strike me as a newcomer, but a warning for the general public: If you break something in the catalog tables, your database (cluster) might go belly-up. You have been warned.

Comment: love your answers.  Can a commenter accept an answer?  Heh

Comment: @Twelfth: Guess you just did. :)

Comment: @Erwin: I understand that using GUC configuration parameters we can disable few joins or scans and make the optimizer choose a bad plan. Bu t that is not what I wanted to do. I wanted a query to show cardinality estimation error and its influence on the optimizer. You have any idea on this?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thanks for your additional input. As you guessed, I have quite some experience working with PostgreSQL source code. The statistics override mechanism that you mentioned is fine. But unfortunately that doesnt solve my problem. I am interested in true cardinality estimation errors made by optimizer inspite of all up-to date statistics.

Comment: @TheGame: That's a very specific question. If I knew an answer to that, I'd better be filing a bug report - unless it is an error that can't be fixed. Can't think of anything ...